# h2 is not enabled in remote IIS

Tags: windows, iis, https, http2

[valid certificate under Server Certificates in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NobKF.png)

[certificate added to https binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEawq.png)

I have a valid trusted certificate provided by my organization and followed the steps provided in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis) to enable the Http/2 protocol on IIS. But when I host a simple project through the remote IIS, the protocol in the browser's Network tab shows as http 1.1.

How could I confirm that Http/2 is enabled in the IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP/2 was not supported before IIS version 10, so first check your iis version. and google chrome offers a quick and easy way to check if HTTP/2 is supported on your SSL-enabled site. First, visit your site in Chrome over HTTPS. There you'll see your site listed with protocol h2, confirming your site works over HTTP/2.

Another method is simply to look at the network tab > headers > response headers > view source in Chrome or Firefox. There the headers can be seen. It should read "HTTP/2" or some sort I can't recall right now. Easiest: You can use curl -I  which will put the HTTP response as the first line.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I see the IIS version of this remote server in the log files from the path - C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles and it is 8.5.  It is much easier to see the way you recommended, Thanks :)

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.